# JPA @OneToMany doesn't save parent ID

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin, relationship, one-to-many

i develop API using Spring Boot and JPA

I found a case in Bidirectional OneToMany relationship, my parent ID doesn't save in DB when requested by JSON payload like this :

```
{
    "name": "Rice",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "variants": [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "unit": "kg",
            "price": 60000
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my Model :

**Product.kt**

```
data class Product(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var photo: String = "",
        var description: String = "",

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JsonBackReference
        var variants: MutableList<Variant> = mutableListOf()
)
```

**Variant.kt**

```
@Entity
data class Variant(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        var id: Long = 0,
        var amount: Int = 0,
        var unit: String = "",
        var price: Double = 0.0,

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        @JsonManagedReference
        var product: Product? = null
)
```

Is there any other configuration need to be applied?
Thank you

Comment: Can you try to set @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false) and see what happens?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I get this error `Column 'product_id' cannot be null` and throw this exception `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that during JSON deserialization the back reference from Variant to Product is not set.

And you define

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
@JsonBackReference
var variants: MutableList<Variant> = mutableListOf()
```

mappedBy says that the back reference is the owning side and therefor in charge for setting the foreign key.

You have two options:

1. Either you set the product reference in Variant before saving the Product
2. or you remove the back reference from Variant to Product and remove the mappedBy = "product" from the variants collection.